# pandas dataframe groupby: apply a function that involves the grouping index value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, aggregate-functions

Let me use this simple df as an example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,10],[1,1,30],[1,2,40],[2,3,50],[2,3,150],[2,4,100]],columns=["col_grp","col1","col2"])

col_grp col1    col2
0   1   1   10
1   1   1   30
2   1   2   40
3   2   3   50
4   2   3   150
5   2   4   100
```

I wish to groupby 'col_grp' and aggregate every other columns into a single value. For example, `grp['col1'].apply(lambda x: x.sum())`.
But instead of a simple 'sum' function f(x)=sum(x), I wish to compute a complicated function which takes not only on the pd.Series of 'col1' as its input, but also the grouping value, i.e., f(x,y). In this example, for the group with 'col_grp' value = 1, the y input is 1. The x input is the 'col1' Series [1,1,2] as usual. Assuming f(x,y) can be coded but its logic a bit complicated for other workaround methods, can I still utilize grp.apply(f)? If yes, how should I write the syntax. Thank you in advance.

I just found something like f(x1,x2) can be applied where x1 is the 'col1' series and x2 is the 'col2' series after grouping. f(x1,x2) returns a single value which is meant to be a statistic of each group. E.g.,

```
grp[['col1','col2']].apply(lambda x: x['col1'].sum() + x['col2'].median())
```

So this could be an effective way to solve my question. Just involve the grouping column into the x input. Like,

```
grp[['col_grp','col1','col2']].apply(lambda x: x['col_grp'].mean() + x['col1'].sum() + x['col2'].median())
```

And I can customize f(x) in anyway I like. I think I answered my own question. Welcome any further discussions:)

Answer (score 1):

Create a group (`grp`) with `.groupby` and create a calculated column using `transform`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,10],[1,1,30],[1,2,40],[2,3,50],[2,3,150],[2,4,100]],columns=["col_grp","col1","col2"])
grp = df.groupby('col_grp')
df['new_col'] = grp['col1'].transform('sum') + grp['col2'].transform('median')
df
Out[1]: 
   col_grp  col1  col2  new_col
0        1     1    10       34
1        1     1    30       34
2        1     2    40       34
3        2     3    50      110
4        2     3   150      110
5        2     4   100      110
```

To make it your own function that you want to customize, you don't have to use `apply`, depending on what you are trying to do.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,10],[1,1,30],[1,2,40],[2,3,50],[2,3,150],[2,4,100]],columns=["col_grp","col1","col2"])

def f(dataframe, col1, col2):
    grp = dataframe.groupby('col_grp')
    return grp[col1].transform('sum') + grp[col2].transform('median')

df['new_col'] = f(df, 'col1', 'col2')    
df
Out[2]: 
   col_grp  col1  col2  new_col
0        1     1    10       34
1        1     1    30       34
2        1     2    40       34
3        2     3    50      110
4        2     3   150      110
5        2     4   100      110
```

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for sharing! I'm still learning these GroupBy methods:) I did not make it clear in the question. My intention of writing customized function is because my "f" manipulation involves nasty for-loop. It is much more nested than the median/sum example I gave. It can be defined when restricted on a single group, but it is hard to be vectorized and applied across groups.

Comment: @YuguangWU hmm, that makes sense, however, it will be tough to help solve without seeing the function itself or an a simpler example of the main ideas of the function that can can make a minimum reproducible example that can be posted on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Create a column from your index:

`df['col_group_copy'] = df.index`

Now you can group by the index, and use the copy in your function

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).